# Sencha Architect 4.3 not update old projects

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

My project work correctly on SA 4.2.9 - Ext 7.3
When the same project is opened with Sencha Architect 4.3, starting update process but "loading instances" window remains open also after 3 hours.
After force exit, on retry to open the project, SA43 request me to update the project...

Same problem on two different computer:

1. Apple Intel with BigSur (CMD 7.3.1.27)
2. Apple M1 with Monterey (CMD 7.4.0.45)

Any idea how fix it?
Are there any log to see the problem?

[Sencha Architect 4.3 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyDB7.jpg)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem but on windows.  I don't think Sencha did much, if any, QA on this latest version of Architect. One way I found that fixed SA hanging was to edit the .started file.  If it contains a 1 change it to 0.  Save file then start SA.
In windows this file is located at:

```
C:\Users\a-win-user\AppData\Roaming\Sencha\Sencha Architect 4.0
```

Not sure where this file would be on a Mac.  Also, if you are using 64 bit version of SA you could try installing the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not gotten it upgraded you may need to update you .xds file.  I had similar issues and followed the instructions from this link:

[Updating SA apps](https://www.sencha.com/blog/upgrading-7-x-sencha-architect-app-to-ext-js-7-6/)